# Write a Cobol copybook?

Tags: cobol, copybook

I'm using a copybook that needs records added to it..

Is it possible to move records to the copybook record and then write out the copybook in COBOL?
If so, any references on how to do this?

I have this code (based on the answer to this question), which is working correctly, however I was told I don't need TRNREC94-OUT, that I can just write the TRNREC94 copybook. When I tried replacing B700-MOVE-RECORDS with "WRITE REPORT-RECORD FROM TRNREC94." I get an error saying that TRNREC94 was not defined as a data-name and was discarded. Not sure where to go from here..

```
 WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                    

 COPY TRNREC94.                          

 01  TRNREC94-OUT.                           
     05 REC-94-TYPE-OUT           PIC X(2).  
     05 REC-94-POLICY-NUMBER-OUT  PIC X(8).  
     05 FILLER                    PIC X(5).  
     05 REC-94-PARISH-CODE-OUT    PIC X(3).  
     05 FILLER                    PIC X(1).  
     05 REC-94-TERRITORY-CODE-OUT PIC X(1).  
     05 FILLER                    PIC X(60). 

...
...

 B700-MOVE-RECORDS.                                          
     MOVE REC-94-TYPE TO REC-94-TYPE-OUT                     
     MOVE REC-94-POLICY-NUMBER TO REC-94-POLICY-NUMBER-OUT   
     MOVE REC-94-PARISH-CODE TO REC-94-PARISH-CODE-OUT       
     MOVE REC-94-TERRITORY-CODE TO REC-94-TERRITORY-CODE-OUT 
     WRITE REPORT-RECORD FROM TRNREC94-OUT.
```

Comment: You need to show people what you have tried, if you do not you get down votes and get told to read the requirements-manual.

Comment: You need to reference the contents of copybook TRNREC94.  There's nothing magic about a copybook.  It's probably an 01 record description.

Comment: Thanks @GilbertLeBlanc, that was all it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the output record is already settup in working storage (in the same format required for the output file), you can do

```
   write Output-Record     from source-record
```

But the more likely case is you will have to move fields one by one to the output record:

```
   Move field-1               to output-field-1 
   Move field-2               to output-field-2 
          ......
   Move field-n               to output-field-n 

   Write Output-Record
```

There is a description of the write statement format here

[IBM Cobol Write Statement](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cbl.doc/rlpswrit.htm)